# How to find : $\lim_{x \to \pi/2}\frac{1-\sin x}{\sin x+\sin 3x}$

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

How to find :

$$\lim_{x \to \pi/2}\frac{1-\sin x}{\sin x+\sin 3x}$$

---

My Try :

$$x-\pi/2=t \to x=t+\frac{\pi}{2}$$

And:

$$ \sin (t+\frac{\pi}{2})=\cos t \\ \sin 3(t+\frac{\pi}{2})=-\cos 3t $$

So :

$$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{1-\cos t}{\cos t-\cos 3t}=\\\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2} \cdot \frac{t^2}{\cos t-\cos 3t}$$

Now what ?

Comment: Pretty sure the limit does exist, friend.

Comment: It does, my bad...

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{1-\sin x}{\sin x + \sin 3x}=\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{1-\sin x}{2\sin 2x\cos x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{1-\sin x}{4\sin x \cos^2 x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{1-\sin x}{4\sin x (1+\sin x)(1-\sin x)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{1}{4\sin x(1+\sin x)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{8}$$

Comment: It's the trigonometric identity $\sin A + \sin B =2 \sin\frac{A+B}{2}\cos\frac{A-B}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\\ \lim _{ t\to 0 } \frac { 1-\cos  t }{ t^{ 2 } } \cdot \frac { t^{ 2 } }{ \cos  t-\cos  3t } =\lim _{ t\to 0 } \frac { \sin ^{ 2 }{ \frac { t }{ 2 }  }  }{ 2{ \left( \frac { t }{ 2 }  \right)  }^{ 2 } } \cdot \frac { t\cdot t }{ 2\sin { t } \sin { 2t }  } =\\ =\lim _{ t\to 0 } \frac { \sin ^{ 2 }{ \frac { t }{ 2 }  }  }{ 2{ \left( \frac { t }{ 2 }  \right)  }^{ 2 } } \cdot \frac { 1 }{ 4\frac { \sin { t }  }{ t } \frac { \sin { 2t }  }{ 2t }  } =\frac { 1 }{ 8 } \\ $$

Answer (score 2):

Some elementary trigonometry will suffice: all you have to know is
$$\sin 3x=3\sin x-4\sin^3x.$$
Indeed, this relation yields
$$\frac{1-\sin x}{\sin x-\sin 3x}=\frac{1-\sin x}{4\sin x-4\sin^3x}=\frac{1-\sin x}{4\sin x(1-\sin^2x)}=\frac1{4\sin x(1+\sin x)}\to\frac18$$

Comment: Which trig identities have you used?

Comment: The first formula: $\sin 3x$ as a cubic polynomial in $\sin x$.

Comment: Cubic polynomial?

Comment: The r.h.s. of the first formula has degree $3$.

Comment: Sorry, did not understand how $sin3x=3sinx-4sin^3x$

Comment: That's a formula I had to learn by heart when I was in high school. To prove is, just write $\sin 3x=\sin(2x+x)$  use the addition formula, then one of the duplication formulæ ($\cos 2x=1-2\sin^2x$) and simplify.

Answer (score 1):

Adding mine to the pile:

$$\require{cancel}\begin{aligned}\frac{1-\cos t}{\cos t\color{blue}{-\cos 3t}}
&=\frac{1-\cos t}{\color{purple}{\cos t}\color{blue}{-\cos^3 t+3\sin^2 t\cos t}}
\\&=\frac{1-\cos t}{\cos t\left(\color{purple}{\sin^2 t+\cancel{\cos^2 t}}-\cancel{\cos^2 t}+3\sin^2 t\right)}
\\&=\frac{1-\cos t}{\color{green}{4\cos t}\sin^2 t}\times\frac{1+\cos t}{\color{orange}{1+\cos t}}
\\&=\frac{1}{\color{green}{4\cos t}\color{orange}{(1+\cos t)}}
\end{aligned}
$$